# Bonescript Unable to find devicetree fragment

Tags: node.js, gpio

I'm working with a BeagleBone Black and trying to get bonescript running. I'm running Debian Wheezy with the latest updates and the latest versions of node v0.10.21 and bonescript 0.2.4. I'm able to blink the internal LED, so I'm fairly certain my installation is working fine. My problem is that I'm unable to control any of the P8 or P9 gpios. Using the examples on the bonescript website I'm running the following script. I'm not sure exactly what this error means so even if someone can point me into the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thank you
Scottt

=============================================

```
var b = require('bonescript');
var led = "P8_3";
var state = 0;

b.pinMode(led, b.output);
toggleLED = function() {
    state = state ? 0 : 1;
    b.digitalWrite(led, state);
};

timer = setInterval(toggleLED, 100);

stopTimer = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
};

setTimeout(stopTimer, 30000);
```

=====================================================
I turned on bonescript debugging and get the following output regarding being unable to find the devicetree fragment.

```
root@debian-armhf:/usr/lib/node_modules/bonescript# nodejs blinkext.js 
debug: cpuinfo = processor      : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 660.76
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware        : Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000

debug: index.js loaded
debug: pinMode(P8_3,,,,);
debug: templateFilename = /usr/lib/node_modules/bonescript/bspm_template.dts
debug: fragment = bspm_P8_3_2f
debug: command = dtc -O dtb -o /lib/firmware/bspm_P8_3_2f-00A0.dtbo -b 0 -@ /lib/firmware/bspm_P8_3_2f-00A0.dts
error: Failed to find devicetree fragment: bspm_P8_3_2f
info:  0: 54:PF--- 
 1: 55:PF--- 
 2: 56:PF--- 
 3: 57:PF--- 
 4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G
 5: ff:P-O-L Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI

debug: Unable to configure mux for pin [object Object]: Error loading devicetree overlay for P8_3 using template bspm
debug: getPinMode(P8_3);
debug: getPinMode(P8_3): Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/pins'
debug: pinMode: mode = {"pin":"P8_3","name":"GPIO1_6","options":["gpmc_ad6","mmc1_dat6","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","gpio1_6"],"gpio":{"allocated":false}}
debug: getPinMode(P8_3);
debug: getPinMode(P8_3): Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/pins'
info: Error loading devicetree overlay for P8_3 using template bspm
```

=======================================================
Here is what I believe is the overlay template bonescript creates.

```
/*
 * This is a template-generated file from BoneScript
 */

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/{
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";
    part_number = "BS_PINMODE_P8_3_0x2f";
    version = "00A0";

    exclusive-use =
        "P8.3",
        "gpio1_6";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            bs_pinmode_P8_3_0x2f: pinmux_bs_pinmode_P8_3_0x2f {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <0x018 0x2f>;
            };
        };
    };
    fragment@1 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        __overlay__ {
            bs_pinmode_P8_3_0x2f_pinmux {
                compatible = "bone-pinmux-helper";
                status = "okay";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&bs_pinmode_P8_3_0x2f>;
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            bs_pinmode_P8_3_0x2f: pinmux_bs_pinmode_P8_3_0x2f {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <0x018 0x2f>;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        __overlay__ {
            bs_pinmode_P8_3_0x2f_pinmux {
                compatible = "bone-pinmux-helper";
                status = "okay";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&bs_pinmode_P8_3_0x2f>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We have forked bonescript and released new package. We faced same error and now solved everything by re-writing lot of code in original bonescript. You can install and use in your projects. https://www.npmjs.org/package/octalbonescript